# Open a text/html Blob in a new tab in safari

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I have a question regarding Blobs in Safari. I have the following function:

```
openTab = () => {
    if (this.printGrid) {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([this.wrapHTMLBody(this.printGrid.innerHTML)], { type: 'text/html;charset=utf-16' })
      );
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      window.open(url).print();
    }
  };
```

In Chrome this code opens a new Tab loads the innerHTML and then opens the print window. The opened HTML then looks like this:

[image: Picture showing the HTML output]

Now when i run this in safari i get this:
[image: Image showing the HTML Output in Safary]

So basically Safari wrapps my content into a  tag. Does anybody know why this is the case and if there is a way to work around it? I couldn't find a lot about this on the web.

I could use file-saver js to save the html. But then the user would have to open the downloaded html and print it manually and that i am trying to avoid. Any help would be appreciated.